# how to get value from unboundCOlumn in wpf Devexpress?

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

[UNboundColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJqru.png)
I need when a new alue enter in unboundColumn in the GridControl, that same value should be shown in the next Column in the same Row ( and that column is not a unboundCOlumn)

```
if (e.IsSetData)
            {
                if (e.Column.FieldName == "Total")
                {
                    if (unboundLocalCurriency.ContainsKey(e.ListSourceRowIndex))
                    {
                        unboundLocalCurriency[e.ListSourceRowIndex] = e.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unboundLocalCurriency.Add(e.ListSourceRowIndex, e.Value);
                    }
                }

            if (e.IsGetData)
            {
                if (e.Column.FieldName == "Total")
                {
                    if (unboundLocalCurriency.ContainsKey(e.ListSourceRowIndex))
                    {
                        e.Value = unboundLocalCurriency[e.ListSourceRowIndex];
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

First name the column `withFieldName="Total"` type `UNbound` like below code:

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="GrdColLocalAmount" Header="Local Amount" FieldName="Total" UnboundType="Decimal" VisibleIndex="4">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:TextEditSettings DisplayFormat="" MaskType="Numeric" Mask="###,###,###.0000000000;(###,###,###.0000000000)" />
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
/dxg:GridColumn>
```

Make the changes in `CellValueChanging` event.